# I would like to filter XSL output based on a Radio button selection

Tags: jquery, xml, forms, xslt

Here is my example I am trying to filter by year based on user selection:
I assume some js or jQuery code would be needed:

XML file:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
 <cd>
  <title>Empire Burlesque3</title>
  <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
  <country>USA</country>
  <company>Columbia</company>
  <price>10.90</price>
  <year>1985</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>Hide your heart</title>
  <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
  <country>UK</country>
  <company>CBS Records</company>
  <price>9.90</price>
  <year>1988</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>Greatest Hits</title>
  <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
  <country>USA</country>
  <company>RCA</company>
  <price>9.90</price>
  <year>1982</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>Still got the blues</title>
  <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
  <country>UK</country>
  <company>Virgin records</company>
  <price>10.20</price>
  <year>1990</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>Eros</title>
  <artist>Eros Ramazzotti</artist>
  <country>EU</country>
  <company>BMG</company>
  <price>9.90</price>
  <year>1997</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>One night only</title>
  <artist>Bee Gees</artist>
  <country>UK</country>
  <company>Polydor</company>
  <price>10.90</price>
  <year>1998</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>Sylvias Mother</title>
  <artist>Dr.Hook</artist>
  <country>UK</country>
  <company>CBS</company>
  <price>8.10</price>
  <year>1973</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>Maggie May</title>
  <artist>Rod Stewart</artist>
  <country>UK</country>
  <company>Pickwick</company>
  <price>8.50</price>
  <year>1990</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>Romanza</title>
  <artist>Andrea Bocelli</artist>
  <country>EU</country>
  <company>Polydor</company>
  <price>10.80</price>
  <year>1996</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>When a man loves a woman</title>
  <artist>Percy Sledge</artist>
  <country>USA</country>
  <company>Atlantic</company>
  <price>8.70</price>
  <year>1987</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>Black angel</title>
  <artist>Savage Rose</artist>
  <country>EU</country>
  <company>Mega</company>
  <price>10.90</price>
  <year>1995</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>1999 Grammy Nominees</title>
  <artist>Many</artist>
  <country>USA</country>
  <company>Grammy</company>
  <price>10.20</price>
  <year>1999</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>For the good times</title>
  <artist>Kenny Rogers</artist>
  <country>UK</country>
  <company>Mucik Master</company>
  <price>8.70</price>
  <year>1995</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>Big Willie style</title>
  <artist>Will Smith</artist>
  <country>USA</country>
  <company>Columbia</company>
  <price>9.90</price>
  <year>1997</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>Tupelo Honey</title>
  <artist>Van Morrison</artist>
  <country>UK</country>
  <company>Polydor</company>
  <price>8.20</price>
  <year>1971</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>Soulsville</title>
  <artist>Jorn Hoel</artist>
  <country>Norway</country>
  <company>WEA</company>
  <price>7.90</price>
  <year>1996</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>The very best of</title>
  <artist>Cat Stevens</artist>
  <country>UK</country>
  <company>Island</company>
  <price>8.90</price>
  <year>1990</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>Stop</title>
  <artist>Sam Brown</artist>
  <country>UK</country>
  <company>A and M</company>
  <price>8.90</price>
  <year>1988</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>Bridge of Spies</title>
  <artist>T`Pau</artist>
  <country>UK</country>
  <company>Siren</company>
  <price>7.90</price>
  <year>1987</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>Private Dancer</title>
  <artist>Tina Turner</artist>
  <country>UK</country>
  <company>Capitol</company>
  <price>8.90</price>
  <year>1983</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>Midt om natten</title>
  <artist>Kim Larsen</artist>
  <country>EU</country>
  <company>Medley</company>
  <price>7.80</price>
  <year>1983</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>Pavarotti Gala Concert</title>
  <artist>Luciano Pavarotti</artist>
  <country>UK</country>
  <company>DECCA</company>
  <price>9.90</price>
  <year>1991</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>The dock of the bay</title>
  <artist>Otis Redding</artist>
  <country>USA</country>
  <company>Atlantic</company>
  <price>7.90</price>
  <year>1987</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>Picture book</title>
  <artist>Simply Red</artist>
  <country>EU</country>
  <company>Elektra</company>
  <price>7.20</price>
  <year>1985</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>Red</title>
  <artist>The Communards</artist>
  <country>UK</country>
  <company>London</company>
  <price>7.80</price>
  <year>1987</year>
 </cd>
 <cd>
  <title>Unchain my heart</title>
  <artist>Joe Cocker</artist>
  <country>USA</country>
  <company>EMI</company>
  <price>8.20</price>
  <year>1987</year>
 </cd>
</catalog>
```

---

XSL File:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body> 
<input type="radio" name="Cost" value="1980" checked="checked"  /> 1980

<input type="radio" name="Cost" value="1990" /> 1990
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Artist</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <xsl:if test="year>1990">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
     </tr>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

A good example for what you're looking for can be found [here](http://maplus.xf.cz/xslt/).

Another hint for your Xsl would be to do without the for-each and use template matching instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" />
    <xsl:param name="year" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="catalog">
        <input type="radio" name="Cost" value="1980" checked="checked"  /> 1980
        <input type="radio" name="Cost" value="1990" /> 1990
        <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
        <table border="1">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cd">
        <xsl:if test="./year &gt; $year">
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```